# How do I redirect all key strokes to remote desktop

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I want to work via a remote desktop connection like with a native installed OS. Hence I set the taskbar on the local OS to "auto hide" so that it doesn't cover the one of the remote desktop. This works fine for me. 
But what I want too is that if I press the <kbd>Win</kbd> key, the start menue of the remote OS should be invoked instead of the start menue of the local computer.

Answer (score 0):

If that's Windows RDP see https://superuser.com/questions/491925/windows-8-shortcut-keys-via-rdp for where you can choose to redirect the windows key.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me. Neither the 'Win' key alone nor any combination with another key like 'WIN' + 'E' isn't redirected to the remote desktop. What works are combinations like 'Ctrl' + 'A' for instance, but a 'Win' key stroke is always directed to the local computer.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder perhaps if it needs to be set the opposite way on the remote machine then.

Comment: Since there is only the connect button available and no option so save the settings without a connect, i think that this setting needs to be done on the local machine side. But still not success. I tried all three options which gives me the same results. Does this work for you?

Comment: You don't have a "show options" drop-down to the left of the connect button? Can you upload a screenshot of your RDP tool?

Also, try opening RDP itself.